# How to return value from a function retreived from SP?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function inside which I am calling SP to retrieve details. My rows[0] contains all the data retrieved from SP. I need to return this value as a return value of a function. 
But each time when I am returning this, I am getting **

> undefined

**.

How to return my result through a function.
Below is my code:

```
    function GetBOMData(BOMName, params, notifySchneiderParam, res, cubicleType, cubicle) {   
      var ret; 
      connection.query('CALL ' + BOMName + '(' + params + ')', function (error, rows, result){
       ret= rows[0];    
    });
    return ret;
}
```

This is how I am calling my function:

```
function GetI06TIncomerBOM(cubicleType, body, res, userID, notifySchneiderParam) {

var operatingVoltageUs = body.TechCharacteristics.OperatingVoltage ? parseFloat(body.TechCharacteristics.OperatingVoltage.replace("kV", "")) : 0;
var packingType = body.TechCharacteristics.PackingType;
var cableDeviceSelected = body.cubicleArray[0].grid.CableTestDevice;
var door500MMSelected = body.cubicleArray[0].grid.depthdoor;
var cableType = body.cubicleArray[0].grid.CableType ? body.cubicleArray[0].grid.CableType : null;
var isNotifiedSchneider = notifySchneiderParam ? 1 : 0;

var params = '"' + cubicleType + '",' + operatingVoltageUs + ',"' + packingType + '",' +
    cableDeviceSelected + ',' + door500MMSelected + ',"' + cableType + '",' + userID + ',' + isNotifiedSchneider;

// Sample SP call : call usp_GetI06TIncomerBOM("I06TIncomer",6,"LandPacking",1,1,"3x1C",5,0) 
var Test = GetBOMData('usp_GetI06TIncomerBOM', params, notifySchneiderParam, res, cubicleType, body.cubicleArray[0]);
return res.json(Test);

   }
```

Comment: When you are calling the SP, you are getting the result asynchronously but your synchronous return statement won't wait for this and will return `undefined` synchronously. You need a callback to return the value instead. Post your code where you are calling this function so that I can post the answer how you can get the result using the callback.

Comment: I have added code on how I am calling this function.

Comment: My problem is even if I write a callback function,the parameters of the function depends on some other function. Hence when I start running the application all my parameter values are null as it hits the callback function first.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer below with the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to the function `GetBOMData` from `GetI06TIncomerBOM` as given below.

You can check this and give a try,

```
function GetBOMData(BOMName, params, notifySchneiderParam, res, cubicleType, cubicle, callback) {   

      connection.query('CALL ' + BOMName + '(' + params + ')', function (error, rows, result){ 
       if(error) {
          callback(error);
       } else {
          callback(null, rows[0]); 
       }   
    });
}
```

And change `GetI06TIncomerBOM` this as below,

```
function GetI06TIncomerBOM(cubicleType, body, res, userID, notifySchneiderParam) {

var operatingVoltageUs = body.TechCharacteristics.OperatingVoltage ? parseFloat(body.TechCharacteristics.OperatingVoltage.replace("kV", "")) : 0;
var packingType = body.TechCharacteristics.PackingType;
var cableDeviceSelected = body.cubicleArray[0].grid.CableTestDevice;
var door500MMSelected = body.cubicleArray[0].grid.depthdoor;
var cableType = body.cubicleArray[0].grid.CableType ? body.cubicleArray[0].grid.CableType : null;
var isNotifiedSchneider = notifySchneiderParam ? 1 : 0;

var params = '"' + cubicleType + '",' + operatingVoltageUs + ',"' + packingType + '",' +
    cableDeviceSelected + ',' + door500MMSelected + ',"' + cableType + '",' + userID + ',' + isNotifiedSchneider;

// Sample SP call : call usp_GetI06TIncomerBOM("I06TIncomer",6,"LandPacking",1,1,"3x1C",5,0) 
var Test = GetBOMData('usp_GetI06TIncomerBOM', params, notifySchneiderParam, res, cubicleType, body.cubicleArray[0], function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        return res.json(result);
    }
});

}
```

Note: I have added the error handling as well.